# How to make the height of a panel depending on other panels?

Tags: javascript, css, panel, materialize

I've got three panels, two on the left side and one on the right.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col s6">
        <div class="panel">
            content1
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            content2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6">
        <div class="panel">
            content3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content of my left two panels is variable and so is the size of the panels.
Now I want the height of the panel on the right be dependent on the size of the left panels i.e. they should be flush at the bottom like in this example:

[image: p]

Is it possible to solve this in pure css or do I need some js function for that?

**Edit:**

I'm using Materialize and I can't figure out how flexboxes work with Materialize.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: No so far I used Materialize.

Comment: I can suggest a possible (straight forward) answer with bootstrap. It requires no `css`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap (v4.2.1) you can make use of the following:

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>This is sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>This is sample text</p>
        <p>This is sample text</p>
        <p>This is sample text</p>
        <p>This is sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>This is sample text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please make sure you [include Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/) in your project.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/) is some extra info regarding Bootstrap's grid system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using bootstrap, you can achieve it with a simple flex layout

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.row{
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.col{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    1<br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    2<br />
    2<br />
    2<br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's tho solution I needed, but I cant get it to work in combination with Materialize.

Answer (score 0):

I hope display flex solves your problem!

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #343434;
}
.col {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.s6 { background-color: #7dc242; }
.s7 { background-color: #ed1c24; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
        <div class="panel">
            content1
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            content2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s7">
         <div class="panel">
            content3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```